# Closing or referencing the websocket from chrome dev console?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, socket.io, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to break my own app that is using socket.io by opening up a socket and sending data to it through the dev console.

I see the web socket open under the network tab, and can see the data it's sending and receiving, however, I cannot right click and grab the reference to send more data, which is fine...

Next thing I tried, was to open up another socket, point it to the same IP/port and try using the same session ID, but that only automatically closes the socket since there is already a socket open for that session ID.

Is there a way to close the open socket, open up one with the same session ID, and send messages through the dev console? Or is there any other way someone can mess with the socket through the dev console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a breakpoint in some scope of the page Javascript that has access to the webSocket object.  It will take some understanding/study of the page's Javascript code to determine where this breakpoint should be set.  Then, run the code that hits the breakpoint.  While sitting at that breakpoint with access to the webSocket object, you can then execute methods on that object to send data over it.

Comment: for some reason though, I have issues saving the file (when saving, it still runs the original code) and actually doing what you said... but this is definitely the right step in the right direction...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "saving".  You can't "save" a change to a web page and expect that change to still be in effect the next time you visit that web page.  The web page source is on the web server and only the web server can permanently "edit" it.

Comment: But in the dev console, you can go under sources, edit the source, save, and you should be running the new edited script... I've done that before, but for some reason this time it is not working... That's the way I was trying to grab the socket. Of course refreshing gets rid of the changes.

So I'm a little confused on how to execute the methods while it's at the breakpoint. So you set the breakpoint on the websocket line and then what? How do you execute the methods?

Comment: @Jaime - at the breakpoint, you can type code into the console and execute it at that specific point in time.  While at the breakpoint, you can access any variables that are within the Javascript scope of the breakpoint (such as the socket object).  This is a one-time hack, not something that works subsequent times you access the page.